# SAS drives not getting detected + orange light

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas

I am using a HP Proliant server with the original hard drives. They have worked before.
I had it powered off for like two weeks.
After trying to power it on again, the two SAS drives had an orange light (was green two weeks prior)
and the RAID controller did not detect it anymore.
All the cables are plugged in fine.
Please help me. I am fairly new, and very desperate.

Answer (score 0):

If the RAID controller doesn't detect the 2 sas disks anymore you can check if it works by changing with new sas disks and see if it recognize it and starts to rebuild your RAID... (You can check this on proliant's utility that monitor and manages your RAID)
If it's so it seems yours disks are broken... otherwaise maybe your controller is not working properly.

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: I have no other disks to test this on :(